# Centroid Point inside wrong Polygon

Tags: pyqgis, point-in-polygon

In this algorithm I need to create points inside every polygon. The easy solution I was thought was using the centroid. With some help of the community we reach in this algorithm

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
import processing


source_layer = iface.addVectorLayer("folder/Polygon.shp", "Setor", "ogr")
crs = source_layer.crs().toWkt()

# Define additional attributes already on the layer level
centroid_layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?field=cd_geocodi:string&crs=' + crs, 'MyPoint' , 'memory')

centroid_layer.startEditing()
# Loop over all features
points = 50
p = 1
while p <= points:
#reading every feature and getting those centroid and one attribute
    for source_feature in source_layer.getFeatures():
        geometry = source_feature.geometry()
        centroid = geometry.centroid()
        name = source_feature.attribute("CD_GEOCODI") # select the attribute

        # Create the new feature with the fields of the memory layer
        # And set geometry and attribute before adding it to the target layer
        centroid_feature = QgsFeature(centroid_layer.fields())
        centroid_feature.setGeometry(centroid)
        centroid_feature['cd_geocodi'] = name
        centroid_layer.addFeature(centroid_feature)
    p += 1
centroid_layer.commitChanges()

# Add the layer to the registry
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(centroid_layer)


#https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_analysis_tools/countpointsinpolygonweighted.html

#counting points inside polygons

Result = "folder/output.shp"
processing.runalg("qgis:countpointsinpolygon", source_layer, centroid_layer, 'NUMPOINTS', Result)
iface.addVectorLayer(Result, 'result', 'ogr')
```

But depending on how unusual is the polygon the centroid is calculated in other polygon, like below:

[image: polygon with 2 points]

I found answers like https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/259185/104521 who makes me think about create a `for` inside another `for`, to use some similar logic to filter the polygon area and insert a random point inside. I had try to adapt these algorithms, but I did not make it. Probably because my skills are limited.

Can someone help me?

Comment: How about PointOnSurface https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools.html?

Comment: The centroid of a concave shape may lie outside the shape itself.  But what is your question?

Comment: Like centroids, I need a point inside every polygon in the layer, and every point will store one attribute of the corresponding polygon

Comment: @whuber, once this occurr, my question is how to insert a point with a random coordinate within every polygon

Comment: It's important that you edit your post to ask that question directly and explicitly.  Your focus on centroids, which aren't relevant to that problem or its solution, looks likely to mislead readers.