# Randomly distribute duplicate points in associated grid cell

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

I have a large point data set consisting of 80k points where each point has an associated attribute value for the grid cell it is within.  The grid is a separate layer.  Many of the points have duplicate geometries and I would like to distribute all duplicate points to a random location within their respective cell.  I have a picture below to show what result I would like.

The grid sizes can also vary by a small amount.

[image]

Comment: @MRXsquared answered it: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404869/redistributing-duplicated-points-inside-the-polygon.